# Doctrine2 integratin with zend framework1

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

```
 Message: Class Application\Entity\Article does not exist
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php(73): ReflectionClass->__construct('Application\Ent...')
#1 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php(867): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getClass('Application\Ent...')
#2 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(517): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->initializeReflection(Object(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService))
#3 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(300): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->initializeReflection(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), Object(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService))
#4 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(205): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Application\Ent...')
#5 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(268): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('Application\Ent...')
#6 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(682): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('Application\Ent...')
#7 /var/www/firsthelp/application/modules/user/controllers/UserController.php(632): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('\Application\En...')
#8 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): User_UserController->configurationAction()
#9 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('configurationAc...')
#10 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#11 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/firsthelp/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#13 /var/www/firsthelp/public/index.php(52): Zend_Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

Could any one help me what i done wrong. I am following this [Bisna] (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/os-doctrine-php-zend/index.html).

Comment: Stacktrace can be helpful but this isn't enough to go on. In general check to see if that class is properly included and I would highly suggest that you get Xdebug or the Zend debugger working/installed. It is a highly invaluable resource!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Set appnamespace = "" (application.ini)
2. Make sure you are using Application namespace with your entities

Comment: Thank you guys. Now i got  what going on . Actually, i forget to create entity path over there. Now it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution :

http://hectorpinol.com/zend-framework-1-11-and-doctrine-2-2-x-integration

And check pdo_mysql extension enabled or not in php.ini